# How to filter on multiple predicates while querying a table in the Spark BigQuery Connector in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

Currently I have a BigQuery table that I want to query from in Spark. This table is partitioned on a date and in order to query this table, one necessarily needs to provide a filter so that BQ can query a specific partition.

I'm using the Spark BigQuery connector: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector and am using code similar to the example provided here:
[image]

However, this takes an extremely long time because the table is several terabytes in size. Doing a `"_PARTITION_DATE > '2019-01-01'"` I believe attempts to load the entire table into a dataframe and then run the query which is entirely unfeasible.

Since the table is already partitioned on date, I was hoping to instead run something like

```scala
.option("filter", "_PARTITION_DATE = '2019-01-01'")
```

but I would like to do this on several different dates. Is there a way to chain these options so that I can query several date predicates simultaneously? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure how bigquery and it's connector works. but if table is partitioned you should get partitioned pruning, and so rather than scanning entire table it should scan only folder/files matching with your predicate.

Comment: This issue seems related to https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/63. And from a line above your screenshot "You can also manually specify the filter option, which will override automatic pushdown and Spark will do the rest of the filtering in the client." So I think that using a filter option won't return only the required partitions. If you could change the pseudo column name _PARTITION_DATE you may be able to use the column in a where statement, which hopefully pushes the request down to the BQ Storage API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following filters, depends on your use case:

- `_PARTITION_DATE BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-07'`
- `_PARTITION_DATE IN ('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01')`